# touchListener not working in Fragment elements

Tags: android, fragment, touch

I have done an implementation in which I have to use fragments with activity all set but when I am trying to implement **touchListener** on fragments any view it's not working.

**Here is my code:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_listfragment, container, false);

        /**
         * Set touch listener for implementing right to left swipe on slide menu
         */
        _view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                //***************** Multi touch events ************************
                int action = (event.getAction() & event.getActionMasked());
                //int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
                //Get the index of the pointer associated with the action.
                int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                int xPos = -1;
                int yPos = -1;

                //***************** Single touch events ************************

                switch (action) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        downX = event.getX();
                        downY = event.getY();
                        return true;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        upX = event.getX();
                        upY = event.getY();
                        float deltaX = downX - upX;
                        float deltaY = downY - upY;

                        // swipe horizontal?
                        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                            // left or right
                            if (deltaX < 0) {
                                //this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                                //((MenuActivity) getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (deltaX > 0) {
                                //this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                                ((MenuActivity) getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();
                                return true;
                            }
                        } else if (Math.abs(deltaX) == 0) {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long horizontally, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            // return false; // We don't consume the event

                            //Single tap implementation
                        }
                        return true; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
                    }// case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        //*******************************************************************


        mOutputRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) _view.findViewById(R.id.outputRecyclerView);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mOutputRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = (screenWidth - screenWidth / 3);
        mOutputRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);

        RelativeLayout settingRl = null;
        ///////////////change screen background based on selected theme//////////////
        mainRl = (RelativeLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.sliderlinearlayout);
        if (SharedPref.getSharedPrefData(getActivity(), SharedPref.SELECTED_THEME).
                equalsIgnoreCase(Util.THEME_LIGHT)) {
            mOutputRecyclerView.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_theme_horizontal_strip_color));
            mainRl.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_theme_horizontal_strip_color));
            settingRl = (RelativeLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.settingLightRl);
        } else {
            mOutputRecyclerView.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color));
            mainRl.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color));
            settingRl = (RelativeLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.settingRl);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Util.overrideFonts(getActivity(), _view.findViewById(R.id.handyTitleTv), 1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                (screenWidth - (screenWidth / 3) - 20),
                (int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.footer_height));
        layoutParam.setMargins(20,
                10, 20,
                20);
        layoutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        settingRl.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);
        settingRl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Set clicklistener for setting option
        settingRl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Util.pressButtonEffect(view);
                Util.isSliderCliked = true;
                ((MenuActivity) getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MhubProFirstSettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Get list of available IR packs for output devices
        if (mIrPackResponsePojo != null) {
            irPackOutputListTable = mIrPackResponsePojo.getIrPackOutputListTable();
        }

        //Sets vertical output device list
        setOutputList();

        //Override fonts for all text view
        Util.overrideFonts(getActivity(), _view.findViewById(R.id.settingLightTv), 1);
        Util.overrideFonts(getActivity(), _view.findViewById(R.id.settingTv), 1);

        return _view;
    }
```

For a solution I implemented **dispacthTouchEvent()** method in my fragment's parent activity so **touchEvents** started working but **onClickListener** events not working on other views.

**Here is my code of activity for dispacthTouchEvent method:**

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();
                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe horizontal?
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        //this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                        //((MenuActivity) getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        //this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                        if (mSlideoutHelper != null)
                            mSlideoutHelper.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(deltaX) == 0) {
                    // return false; // We don't consume the event

                    //Single tap implementation
                }
                return true; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
            }// case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont consume your touch pass it along ;

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                //return false;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();
                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe horizontal?
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        //this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                        //((MenuActivity) getActivity()).getSlideoutHelper().close();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        //this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                        if (mSlideoutHelper != null)
                            mSlideoutHelper.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(deltaX) == 0) {
                    // return false; // We don't consume the event

                    //Single tap implementation
                }
                //return true; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
            }// case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```